# Asp Net Core: Switch between Windows and User Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Is there a best practice in Asp Net Core to switch between Windows and User Authentication (Asp Net Core Identity) on build, depending on for example an option in `appsettings.json`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying it's "best practice", but I can tell you a way that seems good to me to achieve that.

For Windows Authentication, it's mainly a matter of setting up properly your environment. For instance, if you use IIS/Kestrel you have to configure IIS to forward the windows identity, same thing for WebListener ... I've explained that a bit here: [NTLM authentication on specific route in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581132/ntlm-authentication-on-specific-route-in-asp-net-core/42582188#42582188) So, once properly setup, a controller action protected by an `[Authorize]` attribute should get as `HttpContext.User.Identity` a `WindowsIdentity`.

For a standard ASP.Net Core Identity mechanism, you could be using the `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` that would be using a cookie sent alongside with the request to get the identity. Pretty standard.

To combine both depending on some setting coming from `appsettings.json` I would create my own middleware with is quite simple, you need one class derivating from `AuthenticationMiddleware`, one derivating from `AuthenticationHandler` and usually one derivating from `AuthenticationOptions` and depending on my setting in the method `protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticationHandler::HandleAuthenticateAsync()` I would validate the identity coming from Windows or instead branch myself on the code from the `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware`. Good news is ASP.Net Core is open source, so you can actually get all the source from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies` on github.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the app was started with IIS otherwise use Asp Net Core Identity?

Comment: Something I  aksed already here  https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/967 But I don't know a way to do that.