# Windows and Anonymous Authentication in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm trying to mix **Windows** and **Anonymous** authentication in a **.Net Core 2.0** empty web app. I would like to **avoid the [Authorize]** attribute as I do not want to use Mvc or controllers.

My setup is as follows:

1. I created an empty .Net Core 2.0 web application
2. I went to project properties -> Debug -> Checked "Enable Windows Authentication" and disabled "Enable Anonymous Authentication".
   Now "windowsAuthentication": true and "anonymousAuthentication": false appeared in my launchSettings.json under "IIS".
3. Inside Startup.cs, in ConfigureServices I added
   `services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#windows-authentication-httpsys--iisintegration
4. I added a simple `Console.WriteLine(context.User.Identity.Name);` to see that it works inside app.Run and...
   It all works!

However... as soon as I set "anonymousAuthentication" to true in launchSettings.json it stops working and I cannot figure out what can I do to make the Windows authentication work alongside with it. `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always false.
As you can see my configuration is very simple and I need it to stay this way. I want to enable/disable windows authentication on certain dynamic routes, so using controllers with the [Authorize] attribute is not an option.

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple app where the url "/authenticated" would reply with the value of `context.User.Identity.Name` and the url "/public" would reply with something like say "This is a public page!".
Something similar to [NTLM authentication on specific route in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581132/ntlm-authentication-on-specific-route-in-asp-net-core) but without the [Authorize] attribute and controllers.
The resources are very scarce... Anyone have any idea what I could be missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anonymous takes precedence. You need to call httpContext.ChallengeAsync() when you get an anonymous request to a restricted part of your app. That will cause the client to send credentials on the next request. [Here's a test that does this](https://github.com/aspnet/ServerTests/blob/e155b814349f8ff9dd563480d784c38837b0b59f/test/ServerComparison.TestSites/StartupNtlmAuthentication.cs#L34-L59).

Comment: Thank you very much! `context.ChallengeAsync("Windows")` did the trick! I swear I tried await `context.ChallengeAsync()`, but I used "NTLM" as parameter for schema and it told me the authentication schema does not exist... Didn't know what value to pass...

Comment: How to detect if user canceled authentication popup after sending Challenge? I would like to redirect to "LoginFailedPage"

Comment: I don't know that you can. I don't think the browser sends a follow up request. You could include some HTML body in the original 401 response with a link or javascrip timeout redirect back to a login page.

Answer (score 9):

Tratcher's answer saved me after some wasted time on this topic. For a very simple scenario (anonymous controller + windows authentication restricted in the rest), here is a quick start (middleware):

```
public class NtlmAndAnonymousSetupMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public NtlmAndAnonymousSetupMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || context.Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/Anonymous"))
        {
            await next(context);
            return;
        }

        await context.ChallengeAsync("Windows");
    }

}
```

I have just plugged this in at the beginning of `Startup.Configure` method:

```
app.UseMiddleware<NtlmAndAnonymousSetupMiddleware>();
```

Comment: For me, this generates an exception of "No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Windows",...)?"    But I do have an AddAuthentication defined in my Startup.cs