# Angular POST and .NET Core WEB Api - 401 Unauthorized error / CORS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, post, active-directory, cors

I have separate projects for front-end (Angular) and back-end (.NET Core WEB Api).
I have been setup the CORS as well the windows AD authentification. All that is working well for GET calls, but I am having issues with the POST.
I am getting following error.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:50000/api/data/Update 401 (Unauthorized)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:50000/api/data/Update' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Error: Http failure response for http://localhost:50000/api/data/Update: 0 Unknown Error
```

#### user.component.ts

```
update(data: NgForm) {
if (data.form.valid) {
  this.service.update(data.value)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log('Result: ' + res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
    });
  }
}
```

#### service.ts

```
headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Access- 
Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });

update(data: Form) {
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/data/Update', data, { headers: this.headerOptions });
}
```

#### Controller

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public string Update([FromForm] User data)
  {
    if (data != null)
  {
    return "Ok";
  }
    else
  {
    return "Data is null";
  }
}
```

#### CORS extension

```
    public static void ConfigureCors(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", 
                builder => builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
    }
```

I also have the interceptor inside Angular which is sending "withCredentials: true" for all calls.

Have in mind that all my GET calls are working without issues, I only have problems with the POST. If I change the method on Angular side from POST to GET, the Update method from back-end is getting called without issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to hit my controller and POST data after I did following changes:

1. Changed controller attribute from "FromForm" to "FromBody" (thanks to Daniel note about it).
2. Changed angular post method to the following

   ```
    headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    });

    update(data) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/data/Update', JSON.stringify(data), { 
    headers: this.headerOptions });
    }
   ```
3. Set "anonymousAuthentication: true" inside my launchSettings.json.
4. On this stage I had an issue because my user was null on application start, so I had to implement a new middleware found on this question [ntlm anon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084851/windows-and-anonymous-authentication-in-net-core-2-0) in order to handle non-authenticated user on app start.
5. Call middleware inside Configure (Startup.cs), just pay attention on the order. Here is mine:

```
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseAnonMiddleware();
    app.UseAdMiddleware();
    app.UseMvc();
```

And thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Different ports are exactly the same as different applications, therefore your WebApi should allow CORS like

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
```

However, if this is the same application and all you want is that all of the work through the same port then what I think you need to do is:

Add Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions nuget package.

And then configure in you Startup.cs the **Angular Cli** like:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
 {
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default",emplate: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

**Important**:

> To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,  see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

This allows you to have if you want angular running on separate port or the same port as your .net core app.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I have successfully linked both applications angular + .net core, together with windows AD authentication. All GET calls are working without issues, I am having problems with POST calls...