# ASP.NET Core with Cookie and Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication, cookie-authentication

I implemented ASP.NET Core Windows Authentication supporting Cookie

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthenticationScheme")
            .AddCookie("CookieAuthenticationScheme");
```

On Login:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>{new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName)};
await httpContext.SignInAsync("CookieAuthenticationScheme", new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "CookieAuthenticationScheme")));
```

It works okay. But if no one uses the application for a while, and when user logs in the application again it raises this error:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/api/User/GetCurrentUserInfo  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[7]
      CookieAuthenticationScheme was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: (null).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Application.Controllers.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo (Application) in 0.251ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 23.2483ms 401 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/api/User/GetCurrentUserInfo  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[7]
      CookieAuthenticationScheme was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Application.Controllers.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo (Application) in 1.1302ms
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLB9USN79JN9", Request id "0HLB9USN79JN9:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at Interop.Advapi32.LsaLookupSids(SafeLsaPolicyHandle handle, Int32 count, IntPtr[] sids, SafeLsaMemoryHandle& referencedDomains, SafeLsaMemoryHandle& names)
   at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.TranslateToNTAccounts(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceSids, Boolean& someFailed)
   at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceSids, Type targetType, Boolean& someFailed)
   at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceSids, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
   at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(Type targetType)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.<GetName>b__45_0()
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.<>c__DisplayClass61_0.<RunImpersonatedInternal>b__0(Object <state>)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedInternal(SafeAccessTokenHandle token, Action action)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(SafeAccessTokenHandle safeAccessTokenHandle, Action action)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.GetUserNameForLogging(ClaimsPrincipal user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.<AuthorizeAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.<AuthorizeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.<OnAuthorizationAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.<Invoke>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 20.4616ms 500
```

Comment: `services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` in your code isn't doing anything, the next line is overwriting it. that's unrelated to your error though.

Answer (score 2):

The point of windows authentication is to allow the server to do its own thing. When you try using cookies to handle authentication, you're effectively letting the system authenticate, then storing that authentication client side.

The system's authorization for that user is expiring in IIS, but the user's own cookie is saying that they're still authenticated.

I believe what you may actually be trying to do is enable both windows authentication and anonymous users. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44780108/2621693) has some details on how to accomplish this.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42582188/2621693) also seems to support that you do not want cookie auth here.

You may also want to review the setup guide for windows auth in ASP.NET Core [as laid out in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x).